# How to adjust the toolbar according to the ipad orientation

Tags: ipad, orientation, toolbar, uitoolbar, uiinterfaceorientation

I added a toolbar for an ipad application programatically.

```
     UIToolbar *drawToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,710 , 1024, 40)];
     [self.view addSubview:drawToolBar];
     [drawToolBar release];
```

Now it is shown in the bottom of the ipad screen, when in the landscape mode. it comes in to the middle,when it is in the portrait mode.
How can i put it, always in the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) )
    {

        UIToolbar *drawToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,708 , 1024, 40)];
 [self.view addSubview:drawToolBar];
 [drawToolBar release];

    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||  interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        UIToolbar *drawToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,964 , 768, 40)];
 [self.view addSubview:drawToolBar];
 [drawToolBar release];

}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, There is a top toolbar that contains a button. Only this button click bottom toolbar will appear. Like this kind of situation, can we put above coding.

Comment: I try with your code. In landscape mode, it shows corectly. But there are two toolbars. How can i remove the second toolbar

Answer (score 1):

`UIView` has an property called `autoresizingMask` there you can set your struts and springs like in interface builder.

Here is the documentation: [UIView class reference on autoresizingMask](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6)